# How to remove https:// from shortcode generated url

Tags: shortcode

I am using the following code to create a shortcode that generates the url of my website:

```
add_shortcode( 'base_url', 'baseurl_shortcode' );
function baseurl_shortcode( $atts ) {

    return site_url();

}
```

However, when the url is generated it has `https://` at the beginning of it. Is there a way to remove this please?

Comment: (Although it might be helpful to know why you want to remove the https...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be: `return parse_url( get_site_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) );`

Explanation:

[get_site_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) is the WP function that returns the full url (it is the function that `site_url` relies on). [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) is a PHP function that splits the url into several components and returns one or more of them. In this case it returns the hostname, which you seem to be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

That's great, thanks very much!

This is the code I ended up using:

```
// Add site url shortcode
function baseurl_shortcode($atts) {

    return parse_url(site_url(), PHP_URL_HOST);

}
add_shortcode( 'base_url', 'baseurl_shortcode' );
```